# Java Comparator sort by more then one field, count of field should be dynamically

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` data  list. I want to sort list by more then one field. I have no problem if i know count of sorted field. For example if i want to sort list by field which's index is at this position (3,2,5).example is here:

```
public int compare(List<String> rowData1, List<String> rowData2) {
    String[] arr = { "2", "3", "4", "1" };
        String s1 = rowData1.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
            String s2 = rowData2.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
            int comp = s1.compareTo(s2);
            if (comp != 0) {
                result = comp;

            } else {

                String z1 = rowData1.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                String z2 = rowData2.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
                int comp1 = z1.compareTo(z2);
                if (comp1 != 0) {
                    result = comp1;
                } else {

                    String c1 = rowData1.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
                    String c2 = rowData2.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
                    int comp2 = c1.compareTo(c2);
                    if (comp2 != 0) {
                        result = comp2;
                    } else {
                        String b1 = rowData1.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
                        String b2 = rowData2.get(Integer.parseInt(arr[3]));
                        result = b1.compareTo(b2);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I want to have dynamic(configurable) array.  Wait for your suggestion.

Comment: [Use loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: you need to create your own Comparator<ArrayList<String>>, passing the array of indexes you want to sort on in the constructor, then use Collections.sort(list,comparator). There are plenty of answers on stack overflow you can rely upon,

Comment: It is not problem to get array list. I'm getting arrays from configuration. My problem is how to sort List of String array with appropriate index. This  String[] arr = { "2", "3", "4", "1" } array contains appropriate index's and sometimes it's length is 2 and sometimes 4 and so on. It is written in configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean something like this :

```
public class Cumpare implements Comparator<List<String>> {

private final int[] indexes;

public Cumpare(final int[] indexes) {
    this.indexes = indexes;
}


@Override
public int compare(final List<String> o1, final List<String> o2) {
    int value = 0;
    for(int i : indexes){
        value = o1.get(i).compareTo(o2.get(i));
        if (value!=0) break;                        
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you'r help. I wanted to use recursion. I know this solution and this works well. How do you think can i use recursion in this case? My knowledge in algorithm and recursion is not high...